# jQuery get numbers inside paragraph, but not those in classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="content">
  <p>somecontent</p>
  <p>another content <span id="name-1">content</span> 1234214</p>
</div>
```

I want to wrap only numbers in additional span (1234214). So far I've made this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery('.content p').html(function(index, value) {
    return value.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span class="mathjaxfont">$1</span>');
  });
});
```

However this replaces the 1 in span id. How can I exclude checking element attributes?

Comment: what is .entry? there is no entry class in your HTML.

Comment: Sorry "entry" should be "content".

Answer (score 1):

You might want not only to exclude attributes (think about the h1-element for example) but constrain your replacing on the text nodes. See this questions for some ideas on how to get only and work with text nodes: [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)

This answer in above question [How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery/298758#comment929340_298758) gives you a collection of text-nodes on which you can do your string-replacing.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.contents()` and `.replaceWith()` for this:

```
jQuery('.content p').contents().each(function() {
    var method = this.nodeType == 1 ? 'html' : 'replaceWith';
    $(this)[method](this.textContent.replace(
        /(\d+)/g,
        '<span class="mathjaxfont">$1</span>'
    ));
});
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbuckley/r979Ly8h/).

Comment: This removes the span with id="name-1".

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work correctly too... This question is cursed.

Comment: Nice spot - I had a working version but I'd simplified it and not noticed that it removed the span too. I've updated to use `.html()` for elements and `.replaceWith()` for text nodes.

Comment: +1 Looks like it works now... Then my hand-made "reinventing the wheel" hard [solution for this question](http://jsfiddle.net/r979Ly8h/4/) deserves only to be a comment.

Comment: Owh... I found out that it doesn't work on [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/r979Ly8h/5/) :)

Comment: @Regent yeah, I should have mentioned that nested elements aren't supported, but as your answer shows, solving that problem isn't at all easy! :-)

Comment: @cbuckley I actually suppose that there is no easy solution because of necessary mixing of `.text()` with `.html()`... And because of possible nested elements.

Answer (score 0):

Long and hard solution, but should work in nested elements.

The idea is to handle element's `.html()` string character by character, wrapping numbers when they are found, but omitting numbers inside tags' definition.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r979Ly8h/6/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.content p').each(function()
    {
        $(this).html(handleHtml($(this).html()));
    });
});

function handleHtml(html)
{
    var resultHtml = "";
    var numberStr = "";
    var re = /[0-9]/;
    var isTag = false, quote = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < html.length; i++)
    {
        var char = html.substr(i, 1);
        if (!isTag && re.test(char))
        {
            numberStr += char;
        }
        else
        { 
            if (numberStr)
            {
                resultHtml += wrapNumber(numberStr);
                numberStr = "";
            }
            resultHtml += char;
            if (isTag && !quote && (char == '"' || char == "'"))
            {
                quote = char;
            }
            else if (quote && quote == char)
            {
                quote = "";
            }
            if (char == '<')
            {
                isTag = true;
            }
            else if (!quote && char == '>')
            {
                isTag = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (numberStr)
    {
        resultHtml += wrapNumber(numberStr);
    }
    return resultHtml;
}

function wrapNumber(number)
{
    return '<span class="mathjaxfont">' + number+ "</span>";
}
```